# Shared printers published on 14.04 cannot be seen by 12.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, printing, sharing

I have a laser printer connected via USB to my new 14.04lts 64bit desktop installation. It is set as shared and server settings are set to publish.  It prints fine from 14.04 desktop.  I have a laptop with 12.04lts 32bit.  The laptop does not show the printer as shared by 14.04.  On the laptop I have "Show printers shared by other systems" checked.  Before installing 14.04 on my desktop, I had 12.04lts and this setup always worked.
On the laptop, if I select Add a Printer, the printer  shows up as being attached to my desktop with the Add this printer button.  I try adding it and printing to it and Cups says the printer is not responding.  I did not have to Add the printer before 14.04.  Shared printers just showed up and I could print to them.  I've been doing it that way for years.  I thought that was the beauty of Cups.
I have rebooted both desktop and laptop.
Can someone tell me what else to do?
Update, 6/2/14 8:55pm EST: I'm going to switch back to 32 bit PAE until this gets resolved.  I have to get printing going again.  I've never had such trouble in all the many times I've setup Ubuntu for other people.  Usually it just works.  I'll keep checking back in case someone has a solution.

Comment: Just an update.  I reinstalled 12.04. It recognized my printer, automagically.  Thanks Linux programmers.  I selected Server->Settings and checked "Publish shared printers ..." and "Allow users to cancel ...", OK.  Now all the laptops can see the printer via "Show printers shared ...".  It's that simple, but this won't work with a straight up install of 14.04 64 bit.  I'm tempted to install the 14.04 32bit PAE.  If I do, I'll post the results.

Comment: I tried upgrading from 12.04 PAE to 14.04 PAE when offered by the update system and again could not access a printer shared by the new 14.04 system. Does anybody have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong.  I've never run into this with a new install, before.  I'm stuck at 12.04 until I can resolve this issue.